# Filter object array against another object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have two arrays simplified like this.

```
var a = [{
 number: 1,
 name: "A"
}, {
 number: 2,
 name: "B"
}, {
 number: 3,
 name: "C"
}, {
 number: 4,
 name: "D"
}, {
 number: 5,
 name: "E"
}, {
 number: 6,
 name: "F"
}];

var b = [{
 number: 3,
 name: "C"
}, {
 number: 6,
 name: "F"
}];
```

What I want is to return an array where a is filtered against b. So the result is this.

```
var result = [{
 number: 1,
 name: "A"
}, {
 number: 2,
 name: "B"
}, {
 number: 4,
 name: "D"
}, {
 number: 5,
 name: "E"
}];
```

Have looked at alot of other solutions here on stack overflow but can't get it to work.

I am ok with using libaries like underscore.

Comment: what does "filtered against" mean? you want to combine them? you want all the items in the vesica pisces? you want unique items? clarify.

Comment: If you are using lodash(upgraded underscore) you can simply find it using _.differenceBy(). Checkout my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = [{
 number: 1,
 name: "A"
}, {
 number: 2,
 name: "B"
}, {
 number: 3,
 name: "C"
}, {
 number: 4,
 name: "D"
}, {
 number: 5,
 name: "E"
}, {
 number: 6,
 name: "F"
}];

var b = [{
 number: 3,
 name: "C"
}, {
 number: 6,
 name: "F"
}];

var _ = require('lodash');
var result = _.differenceBy(a,b,'name');
```

For more informaiton please refer Lodash documentation: https://lodash.com/docs/#differenceBy

Comment: what if author wants to check not only name field?

Comment: @MaximKuzmin Your solution is better.

Comment: So to use lodash I have to change out all my underscore functions? Doesn't look like they work together.

Comment: @stibay Actually lodash is a clone of underscore with more features(plenty more). It is a good idea to switch to lodash. Most of the functions will be identical, though some may be breaking. Just verify it. Meanwhile you can use(install) each funcitons of lodash individually. Checkout https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized You can install this function alone by npm install lodash.differenceBy

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to achieve with `lodash` by the one-line solution.

```js
var a = [{
 number: 1,
 name: "A"
}, {
 number: 2,
 name: "B"
}, {
 number: 3,
 name: "C"
}, {
 number: 4,
 name: "D"
}, {
 number: 5,
 name: "E"
}, {
 number: 6,
 name: "F"
}];

var b = [{
 number: 3,
 name: "C"
}, {
 number: 6,
 name: "F"
}];

var result = _.differenceWith(a, b, _.isEqual);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Something like that:

```
const filterData = (a,b) => {
    return a.filter( (itemA) => {
        return b.some( (itemB) => { 
            return (itemA.number === itemB.number); 
         });
  });
}
```

I just created a fiddle to test the code: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/pb1qqeyd/3/ (you'll have to open console to check results).

Or... in one-line:

```
const filterData = (a,b) => a.filter( (itemA) => b.some( (itemB) => (itemA.number === itemB.number) ) );
```

**EDIT**: thanks to @kzh suggestions, edited to use [.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: You should probably use `some` instead of `forEach` so that it does not iterate the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built `filter` function in JavaScript to filter an array with another array check the below code snippet.

```js
var a = [{
  number: 1,
  name: "A"
}, {
  number: 2,
  name: "B"
}, {
  number: 3,
  name: "C"
}, {
  number: 4,
  name: "D"
}, {
  number: 5,
  name: "E"
}, {
  number: 6,
  name: "F"
}];

var b = [{
  number: 3,
  name: "C"
}, {
  number: 6,
  name: "F"
}];

var result = a.filter(function(currentValue, index, arr) {
  var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (currentValue.number === b[i].number) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    return currentValue;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plain javascript using `filter()`, `some()` and `every()`.

```js
var a = [{"number":1,"name":"A"},{"number":2,"name":"B"},{"number":3,"name":"C"},{"number":4,"name":"D"},{"number":5,"name":"E"},{"number":6,"name":"F"}]
var b = [{"number":3,"name":"C"},{"number":6,"name":"F"}]

var result = a.filter(function(o) {
  return !b.some(function(e) {
    return Object.keys(o).length == Object.keys(e).length && Object.keys(o).every(function(k) {
      return e[k] == o[k]
    })
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var v1 = JSON.parse(a);
var v2 = JSON.parse(b);

var v3 = [] ;


function objectEquals(v1, v2) {

    if (typeof(v1) !== typeof(v2)) {
        return false;
    }
if (v1 instanceof Object && v2 instanceof Object) {

  for (k in v1) {
            r = objectEquals(v1[k], v2[k]);
            if (!r) {
              v3.push(v1[k]);  

            }
        }



}

}

// call the above method passing your two object, and return a new unique array


objectEquals(v1, v2) ;
```